# Bash what's the difference between $1 and ${1}

Tags: bash

I see some bash scripts use `$1`, `$2`, … to access arguments passed on the command line,  and some scripts use `${1}`, `${2}`, ….  What's the difference between these two syntaxes?

Comment: adding `{}` makes it clear what you're doing. it's the difference between `echo $12` and `echo ${1}2`. first one is accessing the 12th argument to the script, which the other one is the first argument, with a literal `2` appended.

Comment: There is none. However, when you use brackets around the variable's names, you explicitly state the name of the variable to be accessed. This makes a difference when accessing arrays or positional parameters larger than 10 : `$10` won't work, but `${10}` will. With arrays, `$x[5]` won't work, but `${x[5]}` will.

Comment: And it's not just args, it's any environment variable.

Comment: @DonBranson, any *shell* variables. All environment variables (with valid names) are shell variables, but not all shell variables are environment variables.

Comment: @Charles you are correct! I misspoke.

Comment: @MarcB Wrong. `$12` is equivalent to `${1}2`. You can only leave out the braces when your index is a single digit.